# Ajax, asp.net mvc3 routes and relative urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, relative-path

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application published to a url like this:

```
http://servername.com/Applications/ApplicationName/
```

In my code, I am using jquery ajax requests like this:

```
$.get(('a/b/c'), function (data) {}, "json");
```

When I run the application locally, the ajax request goes directly to the correct page (being an mvc route) because the local page ends with a "/" (`localhost/a/b/c`).

However, when I publish to `http://servername.com/Applications/ApplicationName/`, the trailing "/" is not always present. The url could be `http://servername.com/Applications/ApplicationName`, which then causes the ajax request to try to load `http://servername.com/Applications/ApplicationNamea/b/c`, which fails for obvious reasons.

I have already looked into rewriting the url to append a trailing slash, but A) It didn't work, and B) I feel like it's a poor solution to the problem, and that it would be better to configure the javascript urls to work properly regardless of the local folder setup.

I did try "../a/b/c" and "/a/b/c", but neither seemed to work.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I tend to use a global variable of the relative URL of the server in my view like:

```
var BASE_URL = '@Url.Content("~/")';
```

Then you can do things like :

```
$.get(BASE_URL + 'a/b/c'), function (data) {}, "json");
```

I would like to add that if you want it to be totally global, you could add it to your /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml instead.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, and ended up creating two JavaScript functions that mirror the functionality of the MVC Url helper methods `Url.Action` and `Url.Content`. The functions are defined in the _Layout.cshtml file, so are available on all views, and work regardless of whether the application is in the root of the localhost or in a subfolder of a server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UrlAction(action, controller) {
        var url = ('@Url.Action("--Action--","--Controller--")').replace("--Action--", action).replace("--Controller--", controller);
        return url;
    }

    function UrlContent(url) {
        var path = "@Url.Content("~/--file--")";
        path = path.replace("--file--", url.replace('~/', ''));
        return path;
    }
</script>
```

These can then be called like so:

```
var url = UrlAction('AvailableAssetClasses', 'Assessment');
var url2 = UrlContent('~/Images/calendar.gif');
```

Comment: Neat solution. I ended up using the other one but this was useful as well (hence the upvote).

Answer (score 3):

Always use Url helpers when generating urls in an ASP.NET MVC application and never hardcode them. So if this script is directly inside the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("a", "b")';
    $.get(url, function (data) {}, "json");
</script>
```

And if this script is inside a separate javascript file (as it should be) where you don't have access to server side helpers, you could simply put the url in some related DOM element. For example using HTML5 data-* attributes:

```
<div data-url="@Url.Action("a", "b")" id="foo">Click me</div>
```

and then in your javascript file:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.get(url, function (data) {}, "json"); 
});
```

and if you are unobtrusively AJAXifying an anchor or a form, well, you already have the url:

```
$('a#someAnchor').click(function() {
    var url = this.href;
    $.get(url, function (data) {}, "json"); 
    return false;
});
```